# How to get comments of item by using CSOM 2013?

Tags: development, jsom, comments

I retrieve all items by using this code:

```
var oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(title);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(collListItem, x=> x.Take(100));
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var batch in collListItem.Batch(100))
{
     foreach (var item in batch)
     {
          context.Load(item);
     }
     context.ExecuteQuery();
}
return collListItem.Select(Map);
```

Each item has `Comments` field. But, it does not contain all comments.

How to retrieve all comments of item?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the Comments field is a plain multiline text field, then modified the code as below:

```
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev");
            var oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CommentsList");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(collListItem, x => x.Take(100));
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var item in collListItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item["Comments"].ToString());
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is CommentsList hidden list on server? I don't see it if I enumerate all lists.

Comment: There is no CommentsList in SharePoint, this should be a field which allow user to add comment in a list item.

Comment: It has type of SPFieldNote.